# Calculate a point on a map given one point and a distance

Tags: javascript, google-maps, math

I'm working with google maps on an angular project.  I've got a center point of a circle and the length of the radius in meters.  I'm trying to find a coordinate of any point on the circumference of a circle - I just need one.  How do I calculate this given what I have?

Example data :

```
Center = {
   Latitude : 53.388922117675236
   Longitude : -6.280994415283203
}
Radius = 527
```

Comment: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/circle-equations.html

Comment: @NickParsons Sorry,  I should have clarified,  I just need one point

Comment: Ok, a point on the circumference should be `let x = Center.Latitude+Radius` and `let y = Center.Longitude` If I understand your question correctly :P

Comment: That would mean that the x coordinate is 53.388 + 527 = 605.392.  Radius is in meters so I can't add that to a coordinate

Comment: @abyrne85 a distance and a point will give you the infinite points of a circle. If you want only a point, you should provide another constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Maps API has a [geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry#spherical) that you can use to calculate distances, heading, etc.

So if you need to find 1 point at a given distance from another point, whatever heading, you can use the `computeOffset` method.

What the following code does, it adds a marker at position `0,0` (`var myLatLng`) then adds another marker, 5000 meters from that point, at a heading of `0` (North). You can change the heading of course if you need to.

```js
function initialize() {

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: myLatLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    
    var point = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(myLatLng, 5000, 0);
    
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Origin marker'
    });
    
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: point,
        map: map,
        title: 'Offset marker'
    });
}

initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
```

> Note how the API is loaded, with including the geometry library.

Comment: I'm already using the geometry library so this is perfect.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you need arbitrary point at given distance, the simplest way is to choose meridional direction

```
NewLong = Long
NewLat = Lat +- Radius / 111111.111  (meters per degree)
```

Or parallel direction:

```
NewLat = Lat
NewLong = Long +- Radius / 111111.111 / Cos(Lat)
```

For random direction generate random bearing and use formula from [this page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

```
Formula:
φ2 = asin( sin φ1 ⋅ cos δ + cos φ1 ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos θ )
λ2 = λ1 + atan2( sin θ ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos φ1, cos δ − sin φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 )
where   φ is latitude, λ is longitude, 
        θ is the bearing (clockwise from north), 
        δ is the angular distance d/R; 
        d being the distance travelled, R the earth’s radius

JavaScript:(all angles in radians)
var φ2 = Math.asin( Math.sin(φ1)*Math.cos(d/R) +
                    Math.cos(φ1)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(brng) );
var λ2 = λ1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(φ1),
                         Math.cos(d/R)-Math.sin(φ1)*Math.sin(φ2));
```

Comment: This is certainly the right maths. But 1) you didn't provide a Javascript version and 2) you don't need to compute that manually as the API has a method for that (see my answer).

Comment: @MrUpsidown I did not believe that JS guys cannot write given formulas in JS ;)

Comment: Easy ;) But when the question mentions JS, I try to provide JS. Obviously not a big deal! Thanks for updating!